# Getting properties from events in javascript

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'm working on a spotify web application and i'm trying to get some of the audio information out of the [BufferAnalyzer class](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-audio-bufferanalyzer.html)  but i'm having some issues.

```
models.player.load('playing').done(function(){
    var mybuffer =audio.BufferAnalyzer;
    var test = mybuffer.forPlayer(models.player);

    test.addEventListener('audio', function() { 
        //grab field info
    });
});
```

I just want to be able to pull info from the field audio in the BufferAnalyzer class(which Lists of numbers for audio data. This object contains 2 objects, namely "spectrum" and "wave", each with "left" and "right" arrays).

Any idea how I would achive that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the docs:
There are three events: - audio: Triggered when a frame of audio data is ready. field: {boolean} playing Whether audio is being played or buffered. field: {number} deadline Timestamp of when the event will be audible. field: {number} base Frequency interval of the fundamental bands. field: {Object} audio Lists of numbers for audio data. This object contains 2 objects, namely "spectrum" and "wave", each with "left" and "right" arrays. A spectrum array is the loudness of each frequency band (as defined in opt_bands) in decibel, a float with range from -96 (quietest level represented by 16 bit audio) to +12. A wave array is the amplitude of 256 samples of audio (down sampled to 11Khz), a float from 0 to 1.

It sounds like what they are saying is the audio event callback would look like:

```
test.addEventListener('audio', function(playing, deadline, base, audio) {
    // access audio.spectrum.left here
});
```